# Using JAXB with an XML file with many of the same elements

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb, xml-binding

I am working on creating a Java class to map an XML file that has multiple same elements. The following XML is an example of what the file looks like:

```
<TrackBroadcast>
<DateTime>some date</DateTime>
<From>from someone</From>
<To>to someone</To>
<Classification>some type of classification</Classification>
<Command>some type of command</Command>
<MsgId>some id</MsgId>
<Barge attribute1="???" attribute2="???" attribute3="" etc/> --->The Barge.java class explains the attributes
<Barge attribute1="???" attribute2="???" attribute3="" etc/> --->The Barge.java class explains the attributes
<Barge attribute1="???" attribute2="???" attribute3="" etc/> --->The Barge.java class explains the attributes
<Barge attribute1="???" attribute2="???" attribute3="" etc/> --->The Barge.java class explains the attributes
</TrackBroadcast>
```

My JAXB class can read in the DateTime, From, To, Classification, Command, and MsgId elements but it cannot read in the Barge elements.  I have two classes to try to encapsulate the XML but I know I doing something wrong. The two classes are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TrackBroadcast")
public class TrackBroadcast {

    String dataTime;
    String from;
    String to;
    String classification;
    String command;
    String msgId;
    List<Barge> barge = new ArrayList<Barge>();

    public String getDataTime() {
        return dataTime;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="DateTime")
    public void setDataTime(String dataTime) {
        this.dataTime = dataTime;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="From")
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="To")
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getClassification() {
        return classification;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Classification")
    public void setClassification(String classification) {
        this.classification = classification;
    }

    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Command")
    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public String getMsgId() {
        return msgId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="MsgId")
    public void setMsgId(String msgId) {
        this.msgId = msgId;
    }

    public List<Barge> getBarge() {
        return barge;
    }

    public void setBarge(List<Barge> barge) {
        this.barge = barge;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final TrackBroadcast other = (TrackBroadcast) obj;
        if ((this.dataTime == null) ? (other.dataTime != null) : !this.dataTime.equals(other.dataTime)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.from == null) ? (other.from != null) : !this.from.equals(other.from)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.to == null) ? (other.to != null) : !this.to.equals(other.to)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.command == null) ? (other.command != null) : !this.command.equals(other.command)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.msgId == null) ? (other.msgId != null) : !this.msgId.equals(other.msgId)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.barge != other.barge && (this.barge == null || !this.barge.equals(other.barge))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.dataTime != null ? this.dataTime.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.from != null ? this.from.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.to != null ? this.to.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.classification != null ? this.classification.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.command != null ? this.command.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.msgId != null ? this.msgId.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 43 * hash + (this.barge != null ? this.barge.hashCode() : 0);
        for(int i=0; i<barge.size(); i++){
            Barge b = barge.get(i);
            System.out.println(b.toString());
        }
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrackBroadcast{" + "dataTime=" + dataTime + ", from=" + from + ", to=" + to + ", classification=" + classification + ", command=" + command + ", msgId=" + msgId + ", barge=" + barge + '}';
    }
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Barge")
public class Barge {
     String misleBargeVesselId;
     String bargeName;
     String towingVesselName;
     String nonVesselName;
     String towingVesselPhoneNo;
     String towingVesselCompany;
     String positionDate;
     double latitude;
     double longitude;
     String waterwayAbbr;
     double waterwayMileMarker;
     String bargeDirection;
     String bargeCdcType;
     double bargeCdcQuantity;
     String bargeCdcMeasureUnit;
     String bargeLoadStatus;
     String nextEta;


    public String getMisleBargeVesselId() {
        return misleBargeVesselId;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="MISLE_Barge_Vessel_Id")
    public void setMisleBargeVesselId(String misleBargeVesselId) {
        this.misleBargeVesselId = misleBargeVesselId;
    }

    public String getBargeName() {
        return bargeName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_Name")
    public void setBargeName(String bargeName) {
        this.bargeName = bargeName;
    }

    public String getTowingVesselName() {
        return towingVesselName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Towing_Vessel_Name")
    public void setTowingVesselName(String towingVesselName) {
        this.towingVesselName = towingVesselName;
    }

    public String getNonVesselName() {
        return nonVesselName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Non_Vessel_Name")
    public void setNonVesselName(String nonVesselName) {
        this.nonVesselName = nonVesselName;
    }

    public String getTowingVesselPhoneNo() {
        return towingVesselPhoneNo;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Towing_Vessel_Phone_No")
    public void setTowingVesselPhoneNo(String towingVesselPhoneNo) {
        this.towingVesselPhoneNo = towingVesselPhoneNo;
    }

    public String getTowingVesselCompany() {
        return towingVesselCompany;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Towing_Vessel_Company")
    public void setTowingVesselCompany(String towingVesselCompany) {
        this.towingVesselCompany = towingVesselCompany;
    }

    public String getPositionDate() {
        return positionDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Position_Date")
    public void setPositionDate(String positionDate) {
        this.positionDate = positionDate;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Latitude")
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Longitude")
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getWaterwayAbbr() {
        return waterwayAbbr;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Waterway_Abbr")
    public void setWaterwayAbbr(String waterwayAbbr) {
        this.waterwayAbbr = waterwayAbbr;
    }

    public double getWaterwayMileMarker() {
        return waterwayMileMarker;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Waterway_Mile_Marker")
    public void setWaterwayMileMarker(double waerwayMileMarker) {
        this.waterwayMileMarker = waerwayMileMarker;
    }

    public String getBargeDirection() {
        return bargeDirection;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_Direction")
    public void setBargeDirection(String bargeDirection) {
        this.bargeDirection = bargeDirection;
    }

    public String getBargeCdcType() {
        return bargeCdcType;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_CDC_Type")
    public void setBargeCdcType(String bargeCdcType) {
        this.bargeCdcType = bargeCdcType;
    }

    public double getBargeCdcQuantity() {
        return bargeCdcQuantity;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_CDC_Quantity")
    public void setBargeCdcQuantity(double bargeCdcQuantity) {
        this.bargeCdcQuantity = bargeCdcQuantity;
    }

    public String getBargeCdcMeasureUnit() {
        return bargeCdcMeasureUnit;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_CDC_Measure_Unit")
    public void setBargeCdcMeasureUnit(String bargeCdcMeasureUnit) {
        this.bargeCdcMeasureUnit = bargeCdcMeasureUnit;
    }

    public String getBargeLoadStatus() {
        return bargeLoadStatus;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Barge_Load_Status")
    public void setBargeLoadStatus(String bargeLoadStatus) {
        this.bargeLoadStatus = bargeLoadStatus;
    }

    public String getNextEta() {
        return nextEta;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="Next_ETA")
    public void setNextEta(String nextEta) {
        this.nextEta = nextEta;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Barge other = (Barge) obj;
        if ((this.misleBargeVesselId == null) ? (other.misleBargeVesselId != null) : !this.misleBargeVesselId.equals(other.misleBargeVesselId)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.bargeName == null) ? (other.bargeName != null) : !this.bargeName.equals(other.bargeName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.towingVesselName == null) ? (other.towingVesselName != null) : !this.towingVesselName.equals(other.towingVesselName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.nonVesselName == null) ? (other.nonVesselName != null) : !this.nonVesselName.equals(other.nonVesselName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.towingVesselPhoneNo == null) ? (other.towingVesselPhoneNo != null) : !this.towingVesselPhoneNo.equals(other.towingVesselPhoneNo)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.towingVesselCompany == null) ? (other.towingVesselCompany != null) : !this.towingVesselCompany.equals(other.towingVesselCompany)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.positionDate == null) ? (other.positionDate != null) : !this.positionDate.equals(other.positionDate)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.latitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.latitude)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.longitude) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.longitude)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.waterwayAbbr == null) ? (other.waterwayAbbr != null) : !this.waterwayAbbr.equals(other.waterwayAbbr)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.waterwayMileMarker) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.waterwayMileMarker)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.bargeDirection == null) ? (other.bargeDirection != null) : !this.bargeDirection.equals(other.bargeDirection)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.bargeCdcType == null) ? (other.bargeCdcType != null) : !this.bargeCdcType.equals(other.bargeCdcType)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.bargeCdcQuantity) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.bargeCdcQuantity)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.bargeCdcMeasureUnit == null) ? (other.bargeCdcMeasureUnit != null) : !this.bargeCdcMeasureUnit.equals(other.bargeCdcMeasureUnit)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.bargeLoadStatus == null) ? (other.bargeLoadStatus != null) : !this.bargeLoadStatus.equals(other.bargeLoadStatus)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.nextEta == null) ? (other.nextEta != null) : !this.nextEta.equals(other.nextEta)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.misleBargeVesselId != null ? this.misleBargeVesselId.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.bargeName != null ? this.bargeName.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.towingVesselName != null ? this.towingVesselName.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.nonVesselName != null ? this.nonVesselName.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.towingVesselPhoneNo != null ? this.towingVesselPhoneNo.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.towingVesselCompany != null ? this.towingVesselCompany.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.positionDate != null ? this.positionDate.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.latitude) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.latitude) >>> 32));
        hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.longitude) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.longitude) >>> 32));
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.waterwayAbbr != null ? this.waterwayAbbr.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.waterwayMileMarker) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.waterwayMileMarker) >>> 32));
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.bargeDirection != null ? this.bargeDirection.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.bargeCdcType != null ? this.bargeCdcType.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.bargeCdcQuantity) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.bargeCdcQuantity) >>> 32));
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.bargeCdcMeasureUnit != null ? this.bargeCdcMeasureUnit.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.bargeLoadStatus != null ? this.bargeLoadStatus.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.nextEta != null ? this.nextEta.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Barge{" + "misleBargeVesselId=" + misleBargeVesselId + ", bargeName=" + bargeName + ", towingVesselName=" + towingVesselName + ", nonVesselName=" + nonVesselName + ", towingVesselPhoneNo=" + towingVesselPhoneNo + ", towingVesselCompany=" + towingVesselCompany + ", positionDate=" + positionDate + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + ", waterwayAbbr=" + waterwayAbbr + ", waerwayMileMarker=" + waterwayMileMarker + ", bargeDirection=" + bargeDirection + ", bargeCdcType=" + bargeCdcType + ", bargeCdcQuantity=" + bargeCdcQuantity + ", bargeCdcMeasureUnit=" + bargeCdcMeasureUnit + ", bargeLoadStatus=" + bargeLoadStatus + ", nextEta=" + nextEta + '}';
    }
}
```

When I unmarshall the file I can get everything in the TrackBroadcast except for the Barges. I'm new to JAXB and was wondering if anyone could see what I might be doing wrong or if anyone could nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add `@XmlElement(name="Barge")` as by the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) default naming rules JAXB implementations will look for elements with the name `barge` instead of `Barge`:

```
@XmlElement(name="Barge")
public List<Barge> getBarge() {
    return barge;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Just define JAXB @XmlElement annotation with preferred name over required field setter. Also I think that generating classes from XML Schema is a much better option than manually ensuring mapping contract.